# Ace Editor - Syntax rule to get consecutive tokens of same value?

Tags: ace-editor

Consider the following text:

```
Formula1(Formula2(1))
```

I need each right parenthesis to be its own token.

My current rule is the following:

```
{
    token: "parenthesis.right",
    regex: "\\)"
},
```

But this generates one token with value "))" and I need 2 consecutive tokens each with value ")".

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `merge: false` to the rule. see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.3/lib/ace/tokenizer.js#L306

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, thanks! Not sure if it's documented but I totally missed it.